# Pardot Form Handler with external forms

Tags: umbraco, pardot

We are using Pardot handlers with Umbraco forms which is on the server side. There is a big issue going on with the Visitor ID and Country. As the form submission is from the server side, the country on all the prospects in Pardot are coming up the same. Is there any work around it? Is it possible to track the correct country value of the prospect not the server address.

Comment: Any source code or error log to work with?

Comment: Hi Chaitan, There is no source code or error log. I can explain the steps performed. 1) Created the form handlers in Pardot 2) Created Forms in Umbraco. 3) The form handler link is added on the Umbraco form 4) The user submits the form and the data is sent to Pardot. The issue here is all the users submitting the form are coming up with the same country where the Umbraco server is located. Is there any solution to populate the country from where the user is submitting the form instead of the Umbraco server location. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pardot API, you need to manually assign the visitors to the prospects. This is vaguely documented here: http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/visitors/#assigning-and-reassigning-visitors

The basic gist is that you submit your forms record to Pardot, then get the user's visit ID from the cookie with the name "visitor_id" + your_pardot_id. You then need to use the email address from the form to get the prospect ID, using the `/api/prospect/version/4/do/read/email/{email_address}` endpoint. Once you have the two IDs, you can call the `/api/visitor/version/4/do/assign/id/{prospect_id}?prospect_id={visit_id}` endpoint.

This should then correctly associate the front end and back end records so you'l get the missing information for the visitor that's not there because it was a server side submission.

A word of warning though, this process is not fast. Effectively you have to make three calls to the Pardot API and it can be quite slow sometimes.